# How to check if audio file is already loaded with SoundJS?

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm trying to use SoundJS to load sounds dynamically.

If I register a sound that has been already registered with `createjs.Sound.registerSound`, I don't get the callback function to load (called by the "fileload" event listener).

```
createjs.Sound.addEventListener("fileload", createjs.proxy(this.loadHandler, this));
createjs.Sound.registerSound(url, "song");
```

According to a post [here](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/issues/72) and [SoundJS documentation](http://docs.createjs.jp/SoundJS_docs-0.4.0/classes/Sound.html#method_loadComplete), I can check if the sound has been already loaded with `loadComplete(url)`.

But this:

`createjs.Sound.loadComplete("audio/file.mp3")`

...returns:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mp3' of null`.

The problem seems to be that the following function is returning null, because `activePlugin` is null. Why that happens when audio is playing correctly (I'm testing this on Chrome on a Mac)? Shouldn't it be using defaults WebAudioPlugin or HTMLAudioPlugin?

from *soundjs-0.5.2.combined.js*:

```
s.getCapabilities = function () {
    if (s.activePlugin == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return s.activePlugin._capabilities;
};
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a temporary workaround, ugly, but works.

I solved by doing two things:

1) before using for createjs.Sound.loadComplete(url), I first check if createjs.Sound.activePlugin is true.

2) for handling audio files that weren't loaded yet, I added a conditional inside the 
`SoundJS.loadComplete()` function to check if `s._preloadHash[src] === undefined`, and return false if so (that means that URLs that aren't registered urls will return false, as if the file hasn't been loaded):

```
s.loadComplete = function (src) {
    var details = s._parsePath(src);
    if (details) {
        src = s._getSrcById(details.src).src;
    } else {
        src = s._getSrcById(src).src;
    }

    // song has not been registered. return false
    if (s._preloadHash[src] === undefined)
        return false;

    return (s._preloadHash[src][0] == true);  // src only loads once, so if it's true for the first it's true for all
};
```

...and in another JavaScript file:

```
loadSong: function(url){            
    currentSongURL = url;

    // if Sound.activePlugin returns false, load the song.
    if (!createjs.Sound.activePlugin){
        createjs.Sound.addEventListener("fileload", createjs.proxy(this.loadHandler, this));
        createjs.Sound.registerSound(url, url); // url, id
        return;
    }

    // if song is already loaded, resolve deferred.
    if(createjs.Sound.loadComplete(url)) {
        songDeferred.resolve(); 
    }else{
        createjs.Sound.addEventListener("fileload", createjs.proxy(this.loadHandler, this));
        createjs.Sound.registerSound(url, url); // url, id
    }

},
```

I'm studying how to extend `SoundJS.loadComplete()` without messing the SoundJS class, and how to avoid the repeated code on my `loadSong()` function above. It looks very messy indeed but that's what I got for now to make it work the way I intend to. Any help on that would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: [Check this out.](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/SoundJS%20and%20PreloadJS/)

Comment: I guess I have to use PreloadJS, though it doesn't seem to be necessary in this case, considering that SoundJS has a loadComplete() method

Comment: Can you provide the content of the url variable?

Comment: It's "audio/ebbtide.mp3"